# Is there a way to retrieve a document properties without dsolfile?

Tags: vbscript, ms-word

I want to retrieve document properties such as **author**, **last edited by**, etc using vbscript.

Is there a way to get the above info without using **dsolefile** extension ?

Answer (score 1):

Well you *could* parse the file yourself, but Word documents are assentially [structured storage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_Structured_Storage) files. You don't need to read them with [dsOleFile](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;224351), because you can treat them as any structured storage file. It is however convenient to use dsOleFile. Why don't you want to use it?